# loopback update/insert into Oracle package procedure

Tags: node.js, angular, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

How to update using loopback models or loopbackAPI with remote methods or persisted methods so that my JSON can be sent across to a package's procedure of Oracle from my loopback model.
We use Angular 6 with loopback for API.We have successfully done get requests and we have to do post requests which needs to be done on a package of Oracle